# Return count * using callback

Tags: node.js

I have a function like this:

```
function get_users (v_user, callback){
   stmt = db.prepare("SELECT count (*) FROM table_users where option = ?");
   stmt.bind(v_user);

   stmt.get(function(error,row){
      if(row){
         callback(row.count); //? row.count doesn't work
      }
```

My problem is that, I need to do "SELECT count (*)" in my query but I don't know how to put in my callback because "row.count" doesn't work. Somebody know how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: So did you try console.log(row)? What is the output?

Comment: Yes, the output is : [object Object]

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(row, null, 4))`

Comment: Good :) my result is: { "count (*)": 3 }
But if in my callback I need send only "3" ... Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Try to change your query to `SELECT count (*) as count FROM table_users where option = ?` what is the output now?

Comment: Perfect!! work fine :) :) Thanks you very much!

Comment: You are welcome